# Replace multiple characters across all columns pandas df

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, replace

My df has 200+ columns. Some of the column names contain special characters like: `() []` I need to replace all 3 with `_`. I also need to replace empty spaces as well... Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('./pred_results.csv') 

df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r"[()]", "_")
```

With the above code I was only able to replace `()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r"[][() ]", "_", regex=True) 
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r"[][() ]+", "_", regex=True)
```

The first line will replace each separate `]`, `[`, `(`, `)` and space  with a `_`.

The second line will replace a chunk of subsequent `]`, `[`, `(`, `)` and space chars with a single `_`.

Comment: I also need to replace empty spaces in the strings. I edited my question. Do you mind editing your answer? Sorry about that. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: @Chique_Code See update. If you need to replace any whtitespace, replace the space with `\s`.

Comment: Sorry, needed to get back to it. It didn't let me accept right away. All set now. Thanks again!